# Problem importing variables for types in typescript

Tags: typescript, firebase, import, request, google-cloud-functions

ESLint says that Request and Response from first line are unused, but if I remove the lint says the req.headers.authorization dont exist, so I imported then from functions and the intelissense worked, but now says its unused, how can i solve this ? I want to say that the type this parameter of my function is a request, and they have the authorization propertie.

Im using a singleton pattern by the way and this function will be called passing the req and res parameters inside a cloud function

```
import { Request, Response } from 'firebase-functions';
import { auth } from 'firebase-admin';

const authInstance = auth();

export class Authenticator {
  static instance: Authenticator;

  private constructor() {}

  static getInstance() {
    if (Authenticator.instance === null) {
      Authenticator.instance = new Authenticator();
    }
    return Authenticator.instance;
  }

  async authenticate(
    req: Request,
    res: Response,
    log: boolean = false
  ): Promise<void> {
    if (
      !req.headers.authorization ||
      !req.headers.authorization.startsWith('Bearer ')
    ) {
      const response = {
        code: 'auth/missing-argument',
        message: 'Unauthorized Access',
      };

      res.status(401).json(response);
    }

    const token = req.headers.authorization.split('Bearer ')[1];

    try {
      const decodedToken = await authInstance.verifyIdToken(token);

      if (log === true) {
        const user = await authInstance.getUser(decodedToken.uid);
        const logInfo = {
          userId: decodedToken.uid,
          user: user.displayName,
          email: user.email,
          timeGenerated: decodedToken.iat,
          time: new Date().toDateString(),
        };
        console.log(logInfo);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      if (error.code === 'auth/argument-error') {
        const response = {
          code: error.code,
          message:
            'Something wrong with your TOKEN, please make sure that you passed the entire string in JWT format',
        };
        res.status(400).json(response);
      } else if (error.code === 'auth/id-token-expired') {
        const response = {
          code: error.code,
          message:
            'Unauthorized access, your token expired. Get a fresh token from your client and try again',
        };
        res.status(401).json(response);
      } else {
        const response = {
          code: error.code,
          message:
            'Internal Error, check your status code and contact support!',
        };
        res.status(500).json(response);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the eslint option for firebase functions, you’ll need to edit the functions/.eslintrc.json file and add the following:

```
"parserOptions": {
   "ecmaVersion": 2017
},
```

Please let me know if it works for you.